# Big Query : LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join

I am writing an equivalent logic in BQ as in my source system. In source SQL server side it is working fine. But in Big query it is failing with the OR condition in the last left outer join condition. If I am moving the OR condition in the where clause it is giving wrong count. Need help to fix this issue. How can I re write the below query ?

SELECT count(*)

```
            FROM    stprof PRO
                    INNER JOIN stdim DIM 
                        ON (DIM.diSet = PRO.diSet)
                    INNER JOIN DQConfig CFG 
                        ON (CFG.ConSet = PRO.ConSet)
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN AgSt CCT 
                        ON (CCT.StSet = PRO.StSet)
                
                    INNER JOIN stprof SummPRO 
                        ON (SummPRO.diSet = DIM.SummdiSet AND
                                                        SummPRO.dIntervalStart = PRO.dIntervalStart AND
                                                        SummPRO.SiteId = PRO.SiteId AND
                                                        SummPRO.nDuration = PRO.nDuration)
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN AgSt SummCCT 
                        ON (SummCCT.StSet = SummPRO.StSet)
                LEFT OUTER JOIN AgentStatus SummSTS 
                        ON (
                    SummSTS.StSet = SummPRO.StSet
                        OR
                            SummSTS.StSet = PRO.StSet)
            WHERE   DIM.cType = 'A'
```

Comment: `on (summsts.statset = smpr.statset or summsts.statset = smpr.statset)` - are those two two conditions the same? or it is typo?

Comment: I am sorry. that was a mistake. I reposted it again. Thank you

Comment: Would a `coalesce()` be appropriate?

Comment: But how can I use coalesce() here ?

Comment: I have no idea if this is going to true but assuming that one of them is going to be null: `SummSTS.StSet = coalesce(SummPRO.StSet, PRO.StSet)`

Comment: If that doesn't work then you should probably join to that table twice.

Comment: That is not helping

Comment: Are you expecting fanouts with the left joins?  As written, If the join condition fails, that wouldn't affect the count, because you are counting the intersection of all of your inner joins, then because you are left joining, that won't reduce your rows any further.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace LEFT JOIN with CROSS JOIN and move condition from ON clause to WHERE clause as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM stprof PRO
INNER JOIN stdim DIM 
  ON DIM.diSet = PRO.diSet
INNER JOIN DQConfig CFG 
  ON CFG.ConSet = PRO.ConSet
LEFT OUTER JOIN AgSt CCT 
  ON CCT.StSet = PRO.StSet
INNER JOIN stprof SummPRO 
  ON SummPRO.diSet = DIM.SummdiSet 
  AND SummPRO.dIntervalStart = PRO.dIntervalStart 
  AND SummPRO.SiteId = PRO.SiteId 
  AND SummPRO.nDuration = PRO.nDuration
LEFT OUTER JOIN AgSt SummCCT 
  ON SummCCT.StSet = SummPRO.StSet
CROSS JOIN AgentStatus SummSTS 
WHERE DIM.cType = 'A' 
AND (
  SummSTS.StSet = SummPRO.StSet
  OR SummSTS.StSet = PRO.StSet
)
```